# How to determine if mozilla firefox is buggy?

Tags: debug, firefox

I always uses Mozilla Firefox, Since Last 3 days I noticed that I showing some annoying adds on Google Homepage and on Youtube and some javascript popups on other site words while when i checked site and google homepage on chrome its contain no add.
Is my firefox infected, I am using Firefox 19.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

I tried to track by Inspecting element and I found when google home page loaded following urls are fetched

```
[22:02:54.120] GET https://www.google.com/ [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 598ms]
[22:02:54.920] GET https://www.google.co.in/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1515ms]
[22:02:57.797] GET https://i.ssalejs.info/ssale/javascript.js?channel=p2017&hid=512f66f7457e70.42829441 [5925ms]
[22:02:57.799] GET https://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1063/l.js?aoi=1311798366&pid=1399&zoneid=1 [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1623ms]
[22:02:57.800] GET https://www.google.co.in/extern_chrome/2ba1e2da3d78f12.js?bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf. [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 768ms]
[22:02:57.801] GET https://static.getjs.net/amz/aeyJhZmZpZCI6MTAxOCwic3ViYWZmaWQiOjEwMDQsImhyZWYiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY28uaW4vIiwid2lkdGgiOjEzNjYsImhlaWdodCI6NzY4fQ%3D%3D.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2225ms]
[22:02:59.769] GET https://ad.yieldmanager.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&entity=795862&section_code=0_firefox&site_code=1018-1004_WS_google [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2216ms]
[22:03:01.938] GET https://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=728x90&e=795862&S=0_firefox&I=1018-1004_WS_google&T=3&_salt=1538136400&B=10&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&r=0 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 687ms]
[22:03:02.646] GET https://content-ssl.yieldmanager.com/atoms/3c/06/17/f7/3c0617f7509e5ca643d32fcb4135ee61.swf?clickTAG=https%3A%2F%2Fad%2Eyieldmanager%2Ecom%2Fclk%3F3%2CeJyljNGOgjAQRb%2EGNyR0EC1p9mEQa0isKHbX6Jt2uwVkF6OYql8vBuMP7MlkcnIzc4nPPBhpn%2D7pgIx2OvgBRvxvILthQGHoeIwxIDSAkISD0LGTUzZWQizM%2DLQqkgifpHfMlthhUCFuOl%2EQ5%2DY8bPSX7aK6by6dxTyrzvgPdJqrlyaIbb%2DJKR64%2Ek2kF72vYkMEZKWQyptJc93cl42QvBIFybflJ8xkXmzl5JZOk1u6npfCvj8%2EHCdvmuO552MPeDvWWtfUtam0q2q3%2DGujB4sQWz4%3D%2C [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3619ms]
[22:03:05.969] Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString' v=3&s=webhp&action=&e=31215,39523,4000116,4001569,4001947,4001959,4001975,4002159,4002207,4002562,4002734,4002854,4003053,4003178,4003372,4003387,4003496,4003575,4003638,4003715,4003722,4003881,4003917,4003944,4004015,4004065,4004074,4004181,4004214,4004257,4004276,4004309&ei=uIYvUdDfGIjMrQeB5oBI&imc=5&imn=5&imp=0&atyp=csi&adh=&rt=xjsls.652,prt.660,xjses.846,xjsee.935,xjs.948,ol.9682,iml.660,wsrt.275237,cst.188,dnst.0,rqst.914,rspt.640 [HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 250ms]
[22:03:06.526] GET https://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/js/e696e2f636e256c676f6f676/r.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 514ms]
[22:03:06.528] POST https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/n/gcosuc?origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 387ms]
[22:03:06.963] Expected declaration but found '['.  Skipped to next declaration. @ https://www.google.co.in/
[22:03:07.256] GET https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/notifications/frame?sourceid=1&hl=en&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in&uc=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fgapi%2F__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fver%3D24Irvz2rJ1Q.en.%2Fsv%3D1%2Fam%3D!VvZ7oDep-coJNQTnkA%2Fd%3D1#pid=1&rpctoken=312623097&_methods=onError%2ConInfo%2ChideNotificationWidget%2CpostSharedMessage%2Creauth%2CsetNotificationWidgetHeight%2CswitchTo%2CnavigateTo%2CgetNotificationText%2CsetNotificationText%2CsetNotificationAnimation%2ChandlePosted%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart&id=gbsf&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 577ms]
```

Comment: Try disabling all extensions and check if those still show up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today in Chrome, running on Ubuntu 10.04. An advertisement would pop-up on every page that i visited and i fixed the problem installing Chrome's **AdBlocker** (guess you can find something like that also for Mozilla) and it KINDA helped. The adds were gone, but a small **[X]** (for closing the ad) was still appearing in the browser. I installed a **script-blocker** (also a extension from Chrome), and actually didn't tell him to do anything and now everything is back to normal. I also disabled the script blocker and everything is still fine. Who knows whats gonna happen next, hope this maybe helped

A script that i found in my Page Source (and it shouldn't have been there) was this one:

> http://static.getjs.net/amz/aeyJhZmZpZCI6MTAxOCwic3ViYWZmaWQiOjEwMDQsImhyZWYiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDAvIiwid2lkdGgiOjE0NDAsImhlaWdodCI6OTAwfQ%3D%3D.js

Maybe the above link will make it easier for people to find this discussion.